# Why don't you get a type error when you pass a float instead of an int in cython

Tags: cython

I have a cython function:

```
def test(int a, int b):
    return a+b
```

If I call it with:

```
test(0.5, 1)
```

I get the value `1`.

Why doesn't it give a type error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `float` defines the special function `__int__`, which is called by Cython along the way (or more precise [`PyNumber_Long`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Long), at least this is my guess, because it is not easy to [track the call](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/798f08ed8d4c55dedd1597d3ac74cc2a170774a5/Cython/Utility/TypeConversion.c#L827) through all these defines and ifdefs).

That is the deal: If your object defines `__int__` so it can be used as an integer by Cython. Using Cython for implicit type-checking is not very robust.

If you want, you can check, whether the input is an `int`-object like in the following example (for Python3, for Python2 it is a little bit more complex, because there are different `int`-classes):

```
%%cython
from cpython cimport PyLong_Check
def print_me(i):
    if not PyLong_Check(i):
        print("Not an integer!")
    else:
        print(i)
```